# Web2py (save) use of HTML tags in database (text) dleid

Tags: web2py

How can you, in a safe way, enter (en render) hmtl tags in a web2py database textfield. 
Entered by an end user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save the HTML in the database as you receive it, and then render it (relatively) safely via:

```
{{=XML(html, sanitize=True)}}
```

`XML()` also takes `permitted_tags` and `allowed_attributes` arguments for more fine-grained control. For details, see the [book](http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/05#XML).